# Error Restaurar Base de Datos con 'StandBy'

Tags: sql-server

tengo el siguiente Script:

```
Declare @Ruta varchar(max) = 'C:\COM\COMP_20190423_08_40.bak'
RESTORE DATABASE db_prueba
FROM DISK = @Ruta
WITH      
standby = 'C:\COM\db_prueba.tmp',
FILE = 1
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
   No se puede restaurar esta copia de seguridad con WITH STANDBY porque es necesario actualizar la base de datos. Vuelva a emitir la instrucción RESTORE sin la opción WITH STANDBY.
    Mens. 3013, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
    Fin anómalo de RESTORE DATABASE.
```

No sé si alguno me pueda orientar sobre como solventar este error, o si mi Script esta mal.
Mi intención es restaurar la DB y que quede en modo (En Espera\Solo Lectura)
Gracias por su atención.

Comment: ¿Estás restaurando un backup hecho con una versión anterior de SQL Server?, STANDBY solo se puede restaurar si no es necesario actualizar la DB.

Comment: El backup que intento restaurar fue generado con la versión Express 2008, yo tengo la versión Express  2012. ¿Podría ser ese el conflicto?

Comment: Si, si lo necesitas con STANDBY, restaurala en un 2008 también.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba, restaure la DB normalmente en mi versión (2012), luego genere una copia en mi sql (2012) y restaure con STANBY y funciono... Gracias por la ayuda Amigo, me sirvió de mucho tu comentario.

Comment: Pd: ¿No sé si quieras pasar tu comentario a respuesta para marcarte como respuesta?

Comment: Seguro. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mezclando dos operaciones que no son compatibles.

Por un lado, estás actualizando una base de datos, al hacer una copia de seguridad en una versión del motor y luego restaurarla en una versión diferente (mayor).

Por otro lado, estás tratando de restaurar con la opción *standby*.

Pero las operaciones son incompatibles, tienes, básicamente, estas opciones:

- Restaurar la copia de seguridad con *standby* en la misma versión del motor en la que se hizo el backup
- Restaurar la copia de seguridad que tienes, sin la opción *standby* en el nuevo motor, en este caso la recomendación sería hacer un *full backup* en la versión anterior y restaurarlo en la nueva versión.

Puedes encontrar más información en la página de [argumentos del comando restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).